# Wait for asynchronous child process

Tags: linux, bash

I want to combine [Sharenix](https://github.com/Francesco149/sharenix) and [Flameshot](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot) to create screenshots and then upload them to my own host. Well, now my intention was to just create a bash script which I could execute with a shortcut, for example, the "Print Sc" key. Everything could work fine, except that Flameshot creates a child process to take a screenshot and that is currently my biggest problem.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

flameshot gui
sharenix -m c -q
```

This should allow me to get the picture from the clipboard `-m c` and upload it. The other parameter is to disable the output from Sharenix `-q`. But Sharenix tries to upload the file before it even got shot. So well, that means the main process of Flameshot terminated and started a child process.

**Please keep in mind:** Everything works how it should when I execute each command separately.

Is there anything I could do? Maybe check for a clipboard update with bash and the execute Sharenix? I just couldn't find anything on Google after searching for an hour. I hope you understand my question.

Regards.

Comment: Does `flameshot` close file descriptors it inherits above and beyond stdin/stdout/stderr? If not, you can pass it in a `flock()`ed lockfile on a high FD, and then try to grab a second lock on that lockfile -- which will succeed only after the process exits. Using `strace` or `sysdig` is a good place to start to understand its behavior in that respect.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `wait` command between those two?

Comment: @Jack, `wait` won't help here -- it only waits for children the shell knows about. When a process self-daemonizes, it isn't in the shell's job table.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's a good one, I'll try it.

Comment: Hmm. Do you want to wait until it fully completed writing an output file? `inotifywait`  (for a `write_close` event) might be useful, then.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is that in Bash? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: `inotifywait` is not part of bash, but it's a tool you can *use from* bash if it's installed (as part of `inotify-tools`).

Comment: And how can I check for the child process to end?